# Images are not appearing on Front Page

Tags: media

I've looked far and wide and am unable to resolve why my article images are not appearing on the Front Page. (Even disabled my CSS to see if that was interfering with it, but no.)

I have created a simple test Article and uploaded an image, yet when it's promoted to the front page, the image does not display.

Only the title, and body displays. When I click on the article, it displays the image, is there a setting I'm missing for this to display?

Comment: Could you please check if image field is enabled to display on "admin/structure/types/manage/<your content type>/display/teaser" page?

Comment: Yes, teaser is selected in this page. But it's still not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by changing the custom display settings from `teaser` to `full content`. Once the image appeared on the front page, I changed it back to `teaser` and the image now displays correctly on the front page.

I'm guessing it's some bug or conflict with some modules that was causing this.